# Duplicated Magento Categories / Spoofing Hierarchy

Tags: magento, categories

I was wondering if you may be able to give me some direction on the best way to go about achieving the following.

I have a very large Magento (EE v1.12.0.2) store with a category tree set up as below:

-Root Category

- Main category 1

  - Sub category A
  - Sub category C
  - Sub category D
- Main category 2

  - Sub category A
  - Sub category B
  - Sub category C
- Main category 3

  - Sub category B
  - Sub category C
  - Sub category D
- Main category 4

  - Sub category A
  - Sub category B
  - Sub category D

This is primarily for the main category navigation menu, but also so we have landing pages for each of these 4 main categories. So whilst there are '4' sub categories that my products are divided into, they have been duplicated into 12 categories so that they fall under 4 main headings.

Obviously this is sub-optimal but I'm not sure what the best way to approach this would be such that on the front-end our the subcategories are still divided across 4 main categories (with overlap) but on the back-end we aren't duplicating categories, and the categories and their placement can still be maintained through the back-end.

My only thoughts would be something to do with abusing the search results page to mimic the 4 main headings using some attribute to filter on the categories. Would love to your suggestions!

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

By default, it's not possible in magento to assign a child category in multiple parent categories.

In your situation it would be easier to use a custom menu extension to structure your frontend menu however you want. I don't want to recommend a specific extension because I haven't use any of them for Enterprise but you can search for one here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=8&pl=2&hp=0&q=menu&t=0&p=1